# Creating auto scale group fails, "Launch configuration name not found"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I'm trying to create an autoscale group on Amazon. The load balancer is created and is up n' running. I've successfully created the launch configuration in eu-west-1 and it shows up when I run "as-describe-launch-configs". However when I try to create the autoscaling group with this config, it sais "Launch configuration name not found - null".

Any ideas?

```
$ as-describe-launch-configs --region eu-west-1
LAUNCH-CONFIG  wiap_autoscale          ami-8f7466fb  m1.small 

$ as-create-auto-scaling-group wiap-autoscale-group --availability-zones eu-west-1 --launch-configuration wiap_autoscale --min-size 1 --max-size 10 --load-balancers QiiwiWIAP
as-create-auto-scaling-group:  Service error: Launch configuration name not found - null 
AWSRequestId:43131768-d731-11e2-8b76-d168c4c3c890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that it worked if I included this parameter as well:

```
--region eu-west-1
```